# Post to Twitter video with duration more than 30 seconds from iOS App?

Tags: ios, video, twitter, social-networking

I have to upload video about 1 min duration to Twitter from my iOS app, but [Twitter doesn't allow to upload videos more than 30 secs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media#videorecs).

I know that before it was possible to use some 3rd party services like TwitVid, but now all of these services not working.

Is there any solution to upload or embed in Twitter posts videos more than 30 seconds duration?

Comment: Good Questions...With a link